# How to run Transact-SQL with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, plsql, pdo

I have a pl/sql script which is made up of multiple statments:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

**Select values into variable**;

**Build a statment**;

**Prepare and execute statment**;
```

Run directly from the my-sql database this ouputs a standard table of results.

But as I understand it, PDO has issues/limitations when it comes to running multiple statments and returns zero results for me,
what would be the best way to return this queries results as a normal result set?

My experience with PDO has been limited to standard querires so i appologise if this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

First how you can pl-sql statements on MySQL DB ?

However If you have some MySQL statements, You can better create a MySQL Procedure and put code into that.  Then call the procedure through PDO. Like following example from [PDO Prepared Statments](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 

// call the stored procedure
$stmt->execute();
```